# Turn string into an object with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object

How would I return the following string as an object

```
{src:'img/testimage.jpg', coord : {x:17, y:39}, width:200, height, 200}
```

**update**

I have a php file that outputs JSON.  I've used AJAX to to access the JSON in my js.

I've used JSON.parse(json_string) so I now have my object.  This what is returned:

```
[{"name":"img","attributes":"{src:'img\/testimage.jpg', coord : {x:17, y:39}, width:200, height, 200}","comments":"image element with attributes"},{"name":"triangle","attributes":"{bgColor : '#FF0000', coord : {x:500, y:300}, width:50, height, 50}","comments":"triangle"}]
```

I can now use a for loop to go through the bits.

```
for(key in json_object) {
 var name_type = json_object[key].name;
 var attrib = json_object[key].attributes;
}
```

here attrib returns

```
{src:'img/testimage.jpg', coord : {x:17, y:39}, width:200, height, 200}.
```

It is this string that I need to convert into an object.

Thanks
Dave

Comment: It looks like an object to me. If you are getting this as JSON then use `JSON.parse(string)`

Comment: @PSL: Which won't work because it's not valid JSON. At least not what's there right now.

Comment: Please provide more context. How do you get the string?

Comment: @FelixKling oh yeah true, probably this is handtyped... :)

Comment: Where do you get this "string" from? Is it returned from a server?

Comment: _"It is this string that I need to convert into an object."_ This is in fact, already an object. Note though, it a JavaScript object that ***does not*** comply with the JSON spec.

Comment: Time for our old friend `eval`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many have pointed out, you should really store this data as valid *JSON* in the first place and as another post has pointed out your object isn't even a valid javascript object-literal.  How you choose to serialise your data is ultimately your choice but you must at least stick to some rules when encoding it, otherwise how can you expect to parse it?

```
... width:200, height, 200}
                     ^------- Invalid JS Object Notation
```

That said, if for whatever reason you can't easily change your setup (you should aspire to refactor eventually) you can have javascript evaluate the expression **as long as you trust the source**.

```
var str, obj;
str = "{src:'img/testimage.jpg', coord:{x:17, y:39}, width:200, height:200}";
obj = new Function('return '+str)();
```

---

*Related Reading:*

[Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `JSON.parse(string)` but first you need to make your string a valid JSON. which means you have to do the following:

instead of `{src:'img/testimage.jpg'...`  it should be  `{"src":"img/testimage.jpg"...` (note the quotes on the `src`). Each **key** should be wrapped inside quotes `""` or `''`, and each **value** should be exactly how it would be represented as code, for example: a `String` would be wrapped in quotes, an `int` won't;

So your final String would be:

**EDIT**: as War10ck says, the string should be escaped.

```
"{\"src\":\"img/testimage.jpg\", \"coord\":{\"x\":17, \"y\":39}, \"width\":200, \"height\":200}"
```

Comment: This is still not right. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481895/turn-string-into-an-object-with-javascript/#answer-20482158). While you are using double quotes as the spec requires, the internal double quotes (i.e. nested strings) are not properly escaped.

Comment: The thing is, if your `String` was formatted properly, when you go `var attrib = json_object[key].attributes;` it should return an object. If what you're getting is an `String` it's because it is not formatted properly

Comment: I see.  The data is coming from a mysql database. The attributes value in the database is {src:'img/testimage.jpg',and:'so on'}.  So the problem is with string in the database. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not formatted correctly. Should be:

```
{src:'img/testimage.jpg', coord : {x:17, y:39}, width:200, height: 200}
```

(Note the COLON after height, not a COMMA)

Comment: Your JSON is not formatted correctly either. According to the JSON spec strings should be enclosed in double quotes `"`.

Comment: Hello, I've updated my question.  Initially I have a nice valid JSON object. One of the objects inside my object is the string I have mentioned

Comment: If you copied/pasted from your code, you do NOT have a valid (or "parsable", since War10ck is technically correct) JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers point out, you need to have a properly formatted properly escaped JSON string to use `JSON.parse()`. Try this:

```
"{\"src\":\"img/testimage.jpg\", \"coord\":{\"x\":17, \"y\":39}, \"width\":200, \"height\":200}"
```

According to the [JSON Spec](http://www.json.org/), all strings must be enclosed in double quotes `"`. All strings within a JSON string should have properly escaped double quotes `\"`.